# Using arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$ in proofs (metric spaces etc)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Let $A \subseteq X$ and fix $x \in X$, define $\rho(x, A) = \inf \{d(x,a) : a \in A \}$.

In trying to prove $\overline{A} = \{x \in X : \rho(x, A) = 0\}$, if $x \in \overline{A}$ then for all $\varepsilon>0$, $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. So let $y_{\varepsilon} \in B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap A$. By the definition of infimum, we have
\begin{align*}
\rho(x, A) \le d(x, y_{\varepsilon}) < \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Then **since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have $\rho(x, A) = 0$**.

What I don't understand is the bolded part, why is it that just because $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary allows us to conclude $\rho(x, A) =0$? What is the fundamental reason behind this? I've seen this kind of argument using the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$ used elsewhere in really simple arguments, for example:

For all $\varepsilon>0$, assume that $x'+y' > u_1 + u_2 - \varepsilon$ for some real numbers $x', y', u_1, u_2$. Then since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have $x'+y' \ge u_1 + u_2$. Why? I think I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following result with $a = \rho(x,A)$ and $b=0$.

> **Theorem.** Let $a$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a < b + \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$, then $a \leq b$.

(Note that you've already shown the truth of "$a < b + \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$" in your work: when you said that $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, it means you've shown this inequality to be true *for every* $\varepsilon > 0$.)

It then follows from the theorem that $\rho(x,A) \leq 0$. But $\rho(x,A) \geq 0$ by definition of $\rho$, so $\rho(x,A) = 0$.

*Proof of Theorem.* Suppose $a > b$. We show that $a \geq b + \varepsilon$ for *some* $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $\varepsilon = (a-b)/2$, which is positive since $a > b$. Then
$$
a = \dfrac{a+a}{2} > \dfrac{a + b}{2} = b + \dfrac{a-b}{2} = b + \varepsilon.
\tag*{$\blacksquare$}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $\rho(x,A)\neq 0$, then $\varepsilon:=\rho(x,A)/2>0$ and by assumption, one has:
$$\rho(x,A)<\varepsilon=\rho(x,A)/2.$$
Which leads to $1<1/2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental reason is that if you can prove that some non-negative quantity is smaller than **any** positive number $\epsilon>0$ then it must be zero, for if it is not zero, then it is some positive number, for which you can always find some smaller $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you prove that $0\le x<\epsilon$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ then you prove that $0\le x<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

That is, $x$ is a non negative number that is lesser than *any* positive number. Since for any positive number there is another lesser positive number (its half, for example), the only non negative number that holds this condition is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $$\rho(x, A)  < \varepsilon$$ for all $\epsilon>0.$ Can be $$\rho(x, A)  =a>0?$$ Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary we can take $\varepsilon=a/2.$ What do we get in such a case?

$$a=\rho(x, A)<\dfrac a2.$$ This gives us a contradiction. So it must be

$$\rho(x, A) =0.$$

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is a bit cornball, but it is still an earnest attempt to be  instructive.

---

Can the use of '$\text{arbitrary-} \varepsilon$' logic in a proof be an arbitrary choice of techniques? It might even be an indiscriminate choice manifesting abstruseness when other methods are available.

In what follows you will not see any $\varepsilon$'s.

---

Warm up exercise:

Both the infimum and supremum can be expressed in terms of closure:

Assume the set $K \subset \Bbb R$ has NO greatest element but is bounded from above.

Proposition 1: There is a  unique number $k_b \in \overline{K}$ satisfying
$k_b \gt k$ for all $k \in K$.

Proposition 2: The number $k_b$ is the supremum of $K$.

The reader is encouraged to prove both of these statements and the two corresponding  propositions for the infimum.

---

Theorem 3: If $a \gt b$ then there exists a (unique) $p > 0$ so that

$\tag 1  a = b + p$

Proof
If $a \gt b$, then $a - b \gt 0$. Set $p = a - b$. We leave it to the reader to check that (1) holds with this choice of $p$. QED

Corollary 4: If $a \gt b$ then there exists a $q > 0$ so that

$\tag 2  a \ge b + q$

Proof

If you set $q = p/2$ then $a \gt b + q$. But then also $a \ge b + q$, giving (2)  . QED

Of course the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of this corollary is also true:

Theorem 5:  Let $a$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$. If $\,a \lt b + q\;$ for every $q \gt 0$, then $a \leq b$.

Observe that it is OK to use a different letter for $q$, like, say, $\text{e-p-s-i-l-o-n}$.

---

Proposition 6: If $x \in \overline{A}\;$ then $\;\rho(x, A) = 0$.

Proof
Assume $\rho(x, A) = k \gt 0$. It is certainly possible that for some $a \in A $ that $d(x,a) = k$, so we are going to be careful here. The open metric ball about $x$ with radius $k - 10^{-6}$ can't have a nonempty intersection with $A$ (if it did, $\rho(x, A)$ couldn't be a lower bound). So $x \notin \overline{A}$. QED

Exercise: Was it really necessary to be so careful in the above proof?